# Can't get MD5 to get maps api key?

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, key

I made a map app for Android. But when I try to get the MD5 for Map API kety,using the command keytool.exe

```
-list -alias androiddebugkey 
-keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" 
-storepass android -keypass android
```

I get only one sha1 and not the MD5. I am using jdk 7 and Windows 7 32 bit. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JDK 1.7 installed, keytool outputs by default SHA1 fingerprint, not MD5. Adding -v option allows to see MD5 as well.

-v for verbose..